# R: overlay plot on levelplot

Tags: r, plot, levelplot

I have a raster file 'airtemp' and a polygon shapefile 'continents'. I'd like to superimpose the 'continents' on 'airtemp', so the boundary of 'continents' is visible on top of 'airtemp'. I plot the raster file by `levelplot` (lattice). I read the polygon by `readShapeSpatial` (maptools) first and then `plot`.

The problem is `levelplot` and `plot` have different scales. `Plot` tends to have smaller frame. Sorry I don't have a reproducible sample, but I feel this is a rather common issue for geophysicists. I've found a similar question here:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/overlaying-a-levelplot-on-a-map-plot-td2019419.html

but I don't quite understand the solution.

Comment: The answer say , that `levelplot` is a lattice function, `plot` is a base one, very hard to mix base and grid graphics.

Answer (score 12):

You can overlay the shapefile using the `+.trellis` and `layer`
functions from the `latticeExtra` package (which is automatically
loaded with `rasterVis`).

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
```

Let's build some data to play. You can skip this part if you already
have a raster file and a shapefile.

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)

## raster
myRaster <- raster(xmn=-100, xmx=100, ymn=-60, ymx=60)
myRaster <- init(myRaster, runif)

## polygon shapefile
ext <- as.vector(extent(myRaster))

boundaries <- map('worldHires', fill=TRUE,
    xlim=ext[1:2], ylim=ext[3:4],
    plot=FALSE)

## read the map2SpatialPolygons help page for details
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(boundaries$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
bPols <- map2SpatialPolygons(boundaries, IDs=IDs,
                              proj4string=CRS(projection(myRaster)))
```

Now you plot the raster file with `rasterVis::levelplot`, the
shapefile with `sp::sp.polygons`, and the overall graphic is produced
with `+.trellis` and `layer`.

```
levelplot(myRaster) + layer(sp.polygons(bPols))
```

[image: overlay with transparent color]

`sp.polygons` uses a transparent color as default for `fill`, but you can change it:

```
levelplot(myRaster) + layer(sp.polygons(bPols, fill='white', alpha=0.3))
```

[image: overlay with white color]

Comment: Using package tidyverse with this example might create conflict for `map` and `layer`. If you get Error: Attempted to create layer with no geom, use `latticeExtra::layer`.

Comment: what are the "histograms" of the X and Y axis? how can I remove them?

Comment: It is documented in the help page of rasterVis::levelplot, the "margin" argument.

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán would it be possible to fill the polygons with lines (like if you have to shade a polygon)? is there a specific `fill` option?

Comment: @Nemesi That option is not implemented, but you may define your own panel function to get it (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422480/964866)

Answer (score 1):

As per [this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2009-December/007214.html), here is one way of doing this: it consists in breaking the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame into one single matrix of polygons coordinates separated by NAs. Then plotting this on the levelplot using `panel.polygon`.

```
library(maptools)
a <- matrix(rnorm(360*180),nrow=360,ncol=180) #Some random data (=your airtemp)
b <- readShapeSpatial("110-m_land.shp") #I used here a world map from Natural Earth.
```

And that's where the fun begins:

```
lb <- as(b, "SpatialPolygons")
llb <- slot(lb, "polygons")
B <- lapply(llb, slot, "Polygons") #At this point we have a list of SpatialPolygons
coords <- matrix(nrow=0, ncol=2)
for (i in seq_along(B)){
    for (j in seq_along(B[[i]])) {
        crds <- rbind(slot(B[[i]][[j]], "coords"), c(NA, NA)) #the NAs are used to separate the lines
        coords <- rbind(coords, crds)
        }
    }
coords[,1] <- coords[,1]+180 # Because here your levelplot will be ranging from 0 to 360°
coords[,2] <- coords[,2]+90 # and 0 to 180° instead of -180 to 180 and -90 to 90
```

And then comes the plotting:

```
levelplot(a, panel=function(...){
                        panel.levelplot(...)
                        panel.polygon(coords)})
```

The idea in lattice is to define the plotting functions in argument `panel`(see `?xyplot` for a complete explanation on the subject). The function for the levelplot itself is `levelplot`.

[image]

Of course, in your case, it seems way simpler to plot this using `base` graphics:

```
image(seq(-180,180,by=1),seq(-90,90,by=1),a)
plot(b, add=TRUE)
```

[image]